# How To Add .ui Files To Python

Tags: python

1: i create main window in QtCreator.

how i use this form in my python code in eclipse.

2: can write python and build complete python application in QtCreator ? (How).

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

- [A Simple Tutorial On GUI Programming Using Qt Designer With
  PyQt4](http://lionel.textmalaysia.com/a-simple-tutorial-on-gui-programming-using-qt-designer-with-pyqt4.html)
- [Using Qt Designer](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/designer.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need PyQt or PySide to use Qt in your Python script.
To generate python script from ui file run `pyuic -x form.ui`